# bigblue button join API generating link not working

Tags: ruby, bigbluebutton

Post: `localhost:3000/bx_block_classes/meetings/join`

Body:

```json
 {
 "meeting_id": "class-4-gg-135",#generated by create API
 "first_name": "Student", 
 "last_name": "demo",
 "password":"yENfzgxG"
 }
```

Response:

```json
{
    "join_link": "https://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=Studentdemo&meetingID=class-4-gg-135&password=yENfzgxG&checksum=3c2cdf84a2fd2ed521c6a8a6848c22a0f77f3579",
    "is_meeting_running": false
}
```

The join_link generated not working , showing meeting id does not exist.

Comment: When the returned `join_link` doesn't work as expected, then the issue might be in the code generating and returning the link. What does the controller look like? How is the `join_link` generated? Does the code verify that the meeting `id` exists before generating a `join_link`? Or there is an issue in the code handling the request to the `join_link`. What does that controller look like?

Comment: On server it generates link properly which works fine for a certain time and then it gets expired and nobody is able to join through that link.